# Как для команды добавить входные параметры?

Tags: python, telebot, бот

я хочу сделать боту комманду рандомных чисел, она должна выглядеть так: /random 'FirstNum' 'SecondNum'
и в ответе получалось так

- я: /random 0 10
- бот: 5

вот код:

```
import telebot
import random as r
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Тут Токен, Но Ты Его Не Увидеш", parse_mode=None)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def StarterCommands(message):
        bot.reply_to(message, "Что-то")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['spam'])
def StarterCommands(message):
        bot.reply_to(message, "ТЫ?")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['random'])
def RandomNum():
        Num = r.randint(FirstNumber, SecondNumber)
```

Comment: Помню, сам с подобной проблемой столкнулся, но в том случае через регулярные выражения делал, так как мне надо было еще проверить аргументы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аргументы в команду передаются как обычный текст:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['random'])
def RandomNum():
    args = message.text.split() # ['/random', '0', '10']
    if len(message.args) < 3:
        return None

    first_number = args[1]
    second_number = args[2]
    Num = r.randint(first_number, second_number)
```